# How to split dot "." only before equal "=" in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to split a string at a period that comes before an equal sign to assign to a hash. E.g.,

```
"Project.risksPotentialAfterSum=Pot. aft."
```

should be splitted like this:

```
{"Project" =>{"risksPotentialAfterSum" => "Pot. aft."}}
```

For now, I use `str.split(/[\.=]/,2)` which has a problem for the value that comes after the equal sign. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "Project.risksPotentialAfterSum=Pot. aft."
m = str.match(/\A(?<obj>.+?)\.(?<prop>[^.]+?)=(?<val>.+)/)
#=> #<MatchData "Project.risksPotentialAfterSum=Pot. aft." obj:"Project"

h = { m[:obj]=>{ m[:prop]=>m[:val] } }
#=> {"Project"=>{"risksPotentialAfterSum"=>"Pot. aft."}}
```

That regex says, roughly:

- Starting at the start of the string,
- find just about anything on the same line (name it 'obj') up until you see a period,
- that is followed by one or more characters that aren't a period (name it 'prop') up until you see an equals sign,
- and name whatever comes after the equals sign 'val'.

Answer (score 2):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :028 > str
 => "Project.risksPotentialAfterSum=Pot. aft." 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :029 > split = str.split(/\.|=/,3)
 => ["Project", "risksPotentialAfterSum", "Pot. aft."] 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :030 > Hash[*[split[0],Hash[*split[1,2]]]]
 => {"Project"=>{"risksPotentialAfterSum"=>"Pot. aft."}}
```

Concepts used here:

1. Uitlizing the `|` for regex with states: match the left or match the right of `|`.
2. Using the [splat operator](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/08/07/ruby-idioms-what-is-the-splatunary-operator-useful-for/)
3. [Create hash based on list.](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000716)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using string splitting you could consider using regular expression matching and capturing the values that you're interested in.

```
m = "Project.risksPotentialAfterSum=Pot. aft.".match /(\w+)\.(\w+)=(.*)/

h = {m[1] => {m[2] => m[3]}}
#=> {"Project"=>{"risksPotentialAfterSum"=>"Pot. aft."}}
```